# ValueError: from a value returned from a function and casted in int

Tags: python-3.x

I'm a newbie on Python, and I'm facing some challenge to build leverage a function that gets user input, validate if it is a number and if the number is between 1 and 10. Once the string has been validate as a number, I'm casting the input to convert it from "string" to "integer", but it seems it creates some issue :(. I'm a bit stuck and any help is welcome.

Here is my code.

```python
seat = " "
def seat_loop():
    seat = " "
    while seat.isdigit() == False:
    seat = input("Digit a number between 1 and 10: ")
seat_loop()
if int(seat) <= 10:
    if int(seat) >= 0:
        print("The number you entered is: ", seat)
    else:
        print("Type a number bigger than 0")
        seat_loop()
else:
    print("Type a number lower than 10")
    seat_loop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `seat` variable that `seat_loop()` alters is local to the `seat_loop` function and won't change the global variable `seat`, which remains to be `" "` after the call. You should make `seat_loop` return the value and assign returning value to the global variable `seat`:

```
def seat_loop():
    seat = " "
    while seat.isdigit() == False:
        seat = input("Digit a number between 1 and 10: ")
    return seat
seat = seat_loop()
```

Comment: Thanks a million :) I was stuck with something I didn't study yet (but I should have guessed that it was a global-local issue. 
If I run the code, I get asked twice for the input (I also tried to remove the seat = " " within the function and call the function with a parameter seat_loop(seat), but I still get asked twice :s 
I'm using Python 3.6, not sure why the loop runs twice :s

Comment: It's hard to tell without looking at your updated code. You should post your updated code as a new question. In the mean time, please mark this answer as accepted if you think it solves your question.